# How to do small amounts of fluid?

Tags: animation, particles, physics, mantaflow

I want to have some tiny drops of water at a time fall into a mug. I don't want to flood everything. I can't figure out how to do this, help would be greatly appreciated. I've spent the last 5 hours on this. (Also, why do simulations just refuse to work sometimes?)

Comment: They sometimes refuse to work because they are part of the BPUUnion. As for your other question…

Comment: an easy way would be to animate the inflow object scale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to create only a few drops so that it's no problem creating them manually, you could do the following:

In my example I took one sphere and made it a *Flow* object. Although I just want the geometry to become a drop-shaped fluid, I've set the *Flow Behaviour* to *Inflow*.

Then I disabled *Use Flow* on frame 1 and set a keyframe, enabled it on frame 2 and keyframed it, and disabled it again on frame 3 with a keyframe.

Now I duplicated this sphere twice and moved the duplicates to slightly other places (not necessary, but I wanted different locations). After that I moved the keyframes on the *Timeline* to later frames.

Instead of behaving like an inflow, the spheres now create a drop of liquid on that frame which has their *Use Flow* option enabled. Since it's immediately turned off afterwards, the simulation won't be "flooded". Of course the drops could be smaller than the ones in my example.

Result:

[image: drops]

File:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using quick liquid You've set up your three objects, the coffee cup (the effector), the emitter (inflow) and the box to put the simulation in (domain).

You can select the emitter, (inflow) you can turn off the inflow at a certain point in your animation by unchecking the "Use Flow" box and then setting a key:
[image]

In this example, I am preventing my coffee sim from overflow.

Other answers on this forum have said to make just a couple drops fall you can also use meta-balls as particles.  I have tried this with pretty good results.